# How can i order events with esper?

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I want to order events with a value;
So i have found eseper but i couldn't figure out the solution.

I found a example from internet and tried to customize it but failed.

Here are  the codes i've tried.

SampleEvent.java

```java
public class SampleEvent {
    private String item = null;
    private int times = 0;

    public SampleEvent(String item, int times) {
            super();
            this.item = item; 
            this.times = times;
    } 

public String getItem() {
            return item;
    } 

public void setItem(String item) {
            this.item = item;
    } 


public int getTimes() {
            return times;
}

public void setTimes(int times) {
            this.times = times;
}

}
```

SampleListener.java

```
import com.espertech.esper.client.EventBean;
import com.espertech.esper.client.UpdateListener; 

public class SampleListener implements UpdateListener {
        public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents) {
                EventBean event = null;

                event = newEvents[0];
                System.out.println(event.get("item") + ", time = " + event.get("times"));
        }
}
```

SampleEngine.java

```java
package example.esper;

import com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPAdministrator;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPRuntime;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProvider;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPServiceProviderManager;
import com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatement;

public class SampleEngine {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Configuration config = null;
                EPServiceProvider service = null;
                EPStatement stat = null;
                String epl = null;
                SampleListener listener = null;
                EPRuntime runtime = null;

                config = new Configuration();
                config.addEventType("SampleEvent", SampleEvent.class.getName());
                service = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);

                EPAdministrator admin = service.getEPAdministrator();

                EPStatement namedWindowStmt = admin.createEPL("create window orderdEvt.std:unique(item) (item String, times int)");
                epl = "insert into orderdEvt select item, times from SampleEvent GROUP BY times ORDER BY times";
                namedWindowStmt=admin.createEPL(epl);

                listener = new SampleListener();
                namedWindowStmt.addListener(listener);


                runtime = service.getEPRuntime();
                for (int i = 0;i < 20; i++) {
                        try {
                            int j = (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
                             runtime.sendEvent(new SampleEvent("aaa_" + i, j));

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

These codes are doesn't work.
It supposed to be order the events by times.

Is there anyone know how to solve it or any examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Esper is a streaming processor. When ordering events you need to determine which events are being compared (i.e. what is the data windows, if any) and under what condition they are output (every 5 seconds, when X happens, your conditions that cause output).
The current version is 8.2 and the API changed so please use an updated example. They can be found at [esper home page](http://www.espertech.com/esper/).

An example is

```
select * from Event#time(10 seconds) output snapshot every 2 seconds order by value
```